# Grails Run-App results in IOException can't find file 'grails' when building plugin

Tags: java, windows, grails, path, javac

I am attempting to run a grails application and plugin on Windows 7 (x64) from the command line.  I can run the app without the plugin, but when I add the plugin to the project, I get a java.io.IOException with the message `Cannot run program "grails" (in directory "[plugin directory]"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`.  The grails/bin folder is in my system environment path variable, and runs at the command line from the plugin directory just fine.  It is as if the java environment has its own path variable that does not include grails.  Any thoughts?

I have included the full output of the application below, with the path to the plugin project redacted.  I am hoping to demo this project to a customer this afternoon, so rapid help would be much appreciated.

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Compiling 3 source files.....
| Compiling 3 source files.....
| Error Error executing script RunApp: : Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grails" (in directory "[plugin directory]"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grails" (in directory "[plugin directory]"): CreateProcess error=2, The syst
em cannot find the file specified
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:675)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
        at _Events$_run_closure2.doCall(_Events.groovy:35)
        at _Events$_run_closure2.doCall(_Events.groovy)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at _Events$_run_closure3.doCall(_Events.groovy:54)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.BuildListener$targetStarted.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_withTargetEvent_closure1.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:89)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:89)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:35)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grails" (in directory "[plugin directory]"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cann
ot find the file specified
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        ... 58 more
| Error Error executing script RunApp: : Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grails" (in directory "[plugin directory]"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: How does `BuildConfig.groovy` look like?

Comment: I have gisted it [here](https://gist.github.com/therealmitchconnors/0a008f1105cc4658f956).  The client_interface plugin location is identical to the redacted [plugin directory] in the stack trace above.

Comment: Can you add to the question which plugin you were talking about that causes the problem? And you `run-app` from the project directory right?

Comment: The plugin is one that I wrote myself.  The error is occuring when run-app tries to build the plugin from source.